# Clearing shopping cart after checkout

Tags: php, laravel, session, shopping-cart

I have implemented a shopping cart in laravel using sessions. Now, i think I am kinda unclear as to how I would clear the cart for each user after checkout. My understanding is that sessions are created when the browser is open and destroyed when it is closed. I also get that sessions are created on the users machine. How would i go about destroying that session object after user has  checked out?

What, i have is that, a status code would be sent back to a route in my application that would trigger the clear cart function if the payment was successful. Have i misunderstood how sessions operate?

I expect that when a user completes a transaction, the payment gateway will return a code and i could use that code to clear session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can clear the session value for cart on successful transaction.

Assuming you store your cart details in session in a key called **cart**, you can delete it from session like this:

```
$request->session()->forget('cart');
```

or using the helper method like this:

```
session()->forget('cart');
```

This is if the cart details are stored in session, if they are stored in your db, you can begin a mysql (given you are using mysql) transaction at the beginning of your checkout and clear the cart for that particular user. In case of a payment failure, you can rollback the transaction leaving everything intact in cart.

Comment: I have exactly this set up but I'm asking because upon clicking checkout, they are taken to a different domain to handle payments. Would i need to redirect them back to my application inorder to clear the session?

Comment: Yes, don't you have a relay/response url with your payment gateway? Must have, how else would you confirm payments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!